# Can we fetch custom logs in Azure OMS

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-oms

Our Project is a Java Spring boot application, We have a logging system using log4j, Which we are pushing into the Azure Storage accounts.

Question:
I want to query these custom logs in OMS. (Is it possible)
If Yes how.

Till now what i have tried is.
1. Pushed the logs in Blob storage using Logback and container looks like
[image: Blob Storage]

2. Pushed logs in table storage 
   [image]

And configured Storage accounts in log analytics in Azure workspace
[image]

But i am unable to see any Analytic data to query in OMS . 
Please help.

Comment: You can use [Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36072983/7073340) to collect and query the logs directly from your Java application instead of storing it in blobs/tables

Comment: @Jayendran Is there a way in OMS, because our overall application architecture is having logging query in OMS

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Application Insights, you can read logs files from Storage and use HTTP Data Collector API to push logs into Log Analytics workspace. Samples and reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-collector-api